# class field has both @Autowired annotation and right hand assignment

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot

In the source code for Spring Boot I'm confused by a class field that has both the `@Autowired` annotation and right hand assignment.

```
@Autowired
private ResourceProperties resourceProperties = new ResourceProperties();
```

Located at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java

In other words, this field is configured for field injection but it's also directly assigned using the `new` operator. What is actually assigned to this variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the instance is created, the initialization expression's value will be assigned to the field. When the `AutowiredBeanPostProcessor` processes the field it will assign a new value to it.

You'd write code like this if you expected to run the same class outside the context of Spring.